# how to use javax.validation with Thymeleaf

Tags: validation, thymeleaf

When I run this it will create a new book if valid however upon error it will not post back to the page and I get a 400:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as   a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='book'. Error count: 4
```

I tested with system outs, it never gets to the submit if it has errors, I think maybe @Valid is wrong or ???
This is my controller... please tell me what's missing ?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BookController{

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model) {

    refData = new ReferenceData();
    model.addAttribute("refData", refData);

    model.addAttribute("book", new Book());

    List<Book> books = BookRepo.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("books", books);

    return "home";
}   

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@Valid Book book,Model model, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    refData = new ReferenceData();
    model.addAttribute("refData", refData);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "home";
    }

    BookRepo.save(book);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

My form looks like this...

```
<form name="addForm" action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${book}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="*{title}">Book:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{title}" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('title')}" th:errors="*{title}">Name
                Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="*{author}">Author:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{author}" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('author')}" th:errors="*{author}">Author
                Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="*{genre}">Genre:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{genre}" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('genre')}" th:errors="*{genre}">genre
                Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="*{pages}">Pages:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{pages}" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('pages')}" th:errors="*{pages}">pages
                Error</td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
            <td><label th:for="*{year}">Year:</label></td>
            <td>
            <select th:field="*{year}" ng-model="bookData.year">
                <option th:each="selectItem: ${refData.years}"
                    th:value="${selectItem.value}" th:text="${selectItem.label}">year</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('year')}" th:errors="*{year}">year
                Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label th:for="*{rating}">Rating:</label></td>
            <td><select th:field="*{rating}" ng-model="bookData.rating">
                    <option th:each="selectItem: ${refData.rating}"
                        th:value="${selectItem.value}" th:text="${selectItem.label}">rating</option>
            </select></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('rating')}" th:errors="*{rating}">rating
                Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

my entity...

```
@Entity
public final class Book
{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$")
private String title;

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$")
private String author;

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$")
private String genre;


@NotNull
@Digits(message="message here", integer=32767, fraction = 0)
private Integer pages;

private String year;
private String rating;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to place the bindingResult directly after the @Valid Book entity thus...

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@Valid Book book,**BindingResult bindingResult**, Model model ) {


    refData = new ReferenceData();
    model.addAttribute("refData", refData);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "home";
    }


    BookRepo.save(book);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Wow what a minor=major mistake !!

Johnny O.